# Incorrect canonical URLs and redirect chains

Tags: config, htaccess, plugin-seomatic, ssl

I have installed SEOMatic. However, I am getting incorrect canonical URLs. Here is an example: https://jenoffvanhulle.com/en/
The URL has a trailing slash, the canonical URL not

A second problem is that I'm having redirect chains. e.g. [www.jenoffvanhulle.com](http://www.jenoffvanhulle.com) -> https://www.jenoffvanhulle.com -> https://jenoffvanhulle.com

It's clear that some settings are not right. Can somebody help me solving both issues please?
Below you find a listing of some relevant settings:

1. htaccess

```
# Redirect www traffic to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

2. general config

```
'siteUrl' => [
'nederlands' => 'https://jenoffvanhulle.com/',
'english' => 'https://jenoffvanhulle.com/en/',
],
```

3. base URL settings in Craft

[image]

4. SSL certificate settings

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest SEOmatic; the issue you're describing is a case where SEOmatic operates the same as Craft CMS does in terms of returning a root URL without a trailing slash, but we [added a fix to SEOmatic 3.3.18](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/blob/v3/CHANGELOG.md#3318---20200831) anyway.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have version 3.3.24 installed

Comment: My guess would be that something else is amiss, maybe a server-side rewrite?

Comment: yes probably, but I can't find out exactly what at this moment. I will look further. thanks anyway for your help